# Using AJAX to Call a CFC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfml

I have a .cfc file and .cfm file. I want to call the function named "sendemail" located on the .cfc file and alert the user once the function completed successfully. I am using jquery so when the user click on the link, it will trigger this function.

This is what I have so far...

index.cfm file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".forgot-pin").click(function(){
    var getSchoolEmail = $("#schoolaccnt").val();

    if (getSchoolEmail == '0'){
        alert ("Please select school");
    }else{
        chkSchoolEmail = function(theAccNumber){
        $.getJSON("/email.cfc",{
            method:'sendemail',
            accnumber: theAccNumber,
            returnformat: 'json'    
        }, function(){
            alert("Your PIN Number has been sent to your email   address.");
        });
    }

    }
});

</script>


<label>Please sign in below:</label>
    <select id="schoolaccnt">
        <option value="0">Select Your School</option>
            <cfoutput query="get_schools">
                <option value="#sch_id#">#sch_name#</option>
            </cfoutput>
    </select>
<span class="forgot-pin">Forgot PIN?</span>
```

email.cfc file

```
<cffunction name="sendemail" access="remote" returnformat = "json" >
<cfargument name="accnumber" required="true" type="string">
<cfset object =  CreateObject("Component","cfobject")>
    <cfquery name="get_schools" datasource="#dsn#">
        SELECT sch_id,sch_name,sch_email_address,sch_pin_num
        FROM   DATABASENAMEHERE
        WHERE sch_id = '#trim(accnumber)#'
    </cfquery><!---  --->
        <cfmail from="EMAIL" to=EMAILPULLEDOUTFROMDATABASE type="html"  subject="Your PIN" >
            Your PIN is <cfoutput>PINGOTFROMDB</cfoutput>
        </cfmail>
    <cfset result = 1>
<cfreturn object>
```

If the user does not know his/her pin, he/she selects from a dropdown and click on the "forgot pin" link and it should alert "pin sent to email address".

My problem:
The jquery is not calling the function. I am not sure if it is structured the correct way OR if I am missing something.

Any thoughts in solving this will be really appreciated!

*********** EDIT ************

```
function sendMyPin(schoolaccnt){
var getschool = document.getElementById("schoolaccnt").value;
    if (getschool == '0') {
        alert("Please select school.");
    } else { 
    DWREngine._execute("email.cfc", null, 'sendemail', getschool, getEmailResult);
    }

function  getEmailResult(emailObject){
alert('Your PIN has been sent to your e-mail.');                
}
```

Now this is not working on CHROME!!! but works fine in IE and FF

Comment: My thoughts are to do one thing at a time.  The first thing is to make sure your function actually works by invoking it from a coldfusion page.

Comment: Press F12 and check the browser console for errors.

Comment: Your JS code is trying to call `send_email_function.cfc`, but you stated the CFC name was `Email.cfc`.

Comment: @DanBracuk It works perfectly. I am sure it is my jquery. Maybe I am missing something or I am using the wrong parameters.

Comment: Worked perfectly?  Just out of curiousity, what did it return?

Comment: @DanBracuk it creates and send an email that is on file. the cf function pulls the data from the db and sends and email. The only thing that I am trying to achieve is to get an alert once this link is clicked and the email has been sent. I hope I explained myself. My apologies in advance.

Comment: There is nothing to apologize for.  The reason I asked the earlier question is that your cfc function appears to return an empty object and your js code seems to be looking for JSON data.  Scott and Peter both made valuable comments.  Make sure you heed them.

Comment: @DanBracuk I decided to change the coding and now I am using 'code' DWREngine._execute to call the cf function but now it is working on IE and FF but not in Chrome.. any ideas? I will add the code

Answer (score 0):

The click handler is only defining a function `chkSchoolEmail = function(theAccNumber){...}`. It does not call it.

```js
$(".forgot-pin").click(function(){
    var getSchoolEmail = $("#schoolaccnt").val();

    if (getSchoolEmail == '0'){
        alert ("Please select school");
    } else {
        $.getJSON("/email.cfc",{
            method:'sendemail',
            accnumber: theAccNumber,
            returnformat: 'json'    
        }, function(){
            alert("Your PIN Number has been sent to your email   address.");
        });
    }
});
```